# Spring Data MongoDB: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DBObject

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using MongoDB with Spring Data. This query works:

```
@Query("{ 'user.token' : ?0 }")
List<Event> findByUserKey(String userKey);
```

But this query does not work and throws "java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DBObject":

```
@Query("'$or':[ { 'user.token' : ?0 } , { 'user.id' : ?0 } ]")
List<Event> findByUserKey(String userKey);
```

I think the query is well written, any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query takes a document. Add the parenthesis around the query string.

```
@Query("{'$or':[ { 'user.token' : ?0 } , { 'user.id' : ?0 } ]}")
List<Event> findByUserKey(String userKey);
```

You will need spring boot 1.5.2 / spring mongo 1.10.1 version for the placeholder to resolve correctly.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1603